# 'preact build' does not finish

Tags: preact

I am new to preact and react. Whenever I build my preact pwa using 'preact build', as per the output the build never reaches 100%. It only goes upto 91% but looking at the built code it seems the build is 100% completed (I have deployed the build and it is working). Can someone please put a light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as everything works as expected you can just ignore that. Seems like it's a small bug in the UI and nothing more. It may or may not be changed in the future